# How to properly use Promise.all() and then() with async functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise, bluebird

In the following code, I am trying to put the results from the first and second query inside a global variable called `result`. The problem is `Promise.all()` is not waiting the queries finish and before proceding to `then()`.

How can I solve it?

Code:

```
var result = {};
Promise.all([
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM analysis', 
    function(err, rows, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;
      result.analysis = rows;
      console.log("query 1");
  }), 
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM analysis_description', 
    function(err, rows, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;
      result.analysis_description = rows;
      console.log("query 2");
  })
])
.then(function(result){
  console.log(result);
  console.log("result");
});
```

Output:

```
result
query 1
query 2
```

Comment: Does `connection.query` return a promise?

Comment: Promise.all takes an array of promises. Those don't look like promises:-)

Comment: You'll need to "promisify" a normal async-callback function to use it as a promise: as a promise is a value that must be immediately returned. There are several ways to achieve this.

Comment: yeah...what everyone else said.  look here - https://github.com/DrkSephy/es6-cheatsheet#promises

Comment: (to chime in) possible duplicate of [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

like said in the comments, you need to promisify the async calls, either manually:

```
queryAsync = query => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  connection.query(query, (err, rows) => {
    if(err) return reject(err)
    resolve(rows)
  })
})
```

or preferred way is using library like [`bluebird`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html):

```
connection  = require('bluebird').promisifyAll(connection)
```

and your code can be modified into:

```
var result = {};
Promise.all([
  connection.queryAsync('SELECT * FROM analysis').then(rows => result.analysis = rows), 
  connection.queryAsync('SELECT * FROM analysis_description').then(rows => result.analysis_description = rows)
]).then(function(result){
  console.log(result);
  console.log("result");
}).catch(e => console.error(e));
```

Comment: The `catch()` will handle every error from the promisified functions too?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everyone! Like everyone said, the problem were in the wrong parameter in `Promise.all()`. This is the code after the changes.

Code:

```
Promise.promisifyAll(require("mysql/lib/Connection").prototype)

var result = {};
Promise.all([
  connection.queryAsync('SELECT * FROM analysis')
  .then(function(rows){
    console.log(rows);
    result.analysis = rows;
  }), 
  connection.queryAsync('SELECT * FROM analysis_description')
  .then(function(rows){
    result.analysis_description = rows;
  })
])
.then(function(){
  console.log(result);
  console.log("result");
});
```